# dotnet new angular twitter bootstrap collapse menu not working

Tags: .net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

Back in April, I ran these two commands:

dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*

dotnet new angular

I got a project created, and out of the box everything worked fine, including the bootstrap-driven collapsable menu. So, when the browser screen width was reduced, to simulate a mobile device, the menu items were hidden and replaced by the toggle navigation button. When that button was clicked, the menu items appeared in a dropdown as expected.

Yesterday I wanted to start a new project, and so I ran the exact same two commands (I re-ran the first to be sure I had the most current templates). The project was created, and at first all looked good. However, as soon as I narrowed the screen width, while the toggle navigation button did appear, clicking on it did nothing. I tried recreating a project several times, but the same problem continues. Right out of the box it does not work.

I don't know how to debug this issue, or what might have changed since April.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I've just tried copying and pasting in the example on bootstraps website and it still doesn't work.  I think there might be something missing.

Comment: It looks like all of the expected event listeners aren't linked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to add this to your app.component.ts at the top:

```
import "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
```

I found the answer this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/960) provided by bm-software

Comment: Thank you, Chris! I had resorted to adding jquery and bootstrap references at the top of the _Layout.cshtml page. That worked, but I knew it was not the right way to do it. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: this worked initially, but now I am finding that whenever I add: import 'bootstrap' to app.component.ts, I get a server build error: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefined.  Any ideas?

Comment: Library versions? im using jquery 3.2.1 and bootstrap 3.3.7. Ordering of import statements? im puting them right at the top of app.component.ts line 1 and 2.

Comment: Same versions of both libraries. I did have them after the Component import from @angular/core, but moving them to the very top of the file did not fix the problem. Strangely, it again worked initially, but after I stopped debugging, cleared my browser's temporary files, then hit F5, the problem appeared again. I am forced to reference the files at the top of the _Layouts file again. ;(

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue recently.
after adding these lines on topmost of app.component.ts

```
import "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
```

make sure you add jquery on your package.json

```
"jquery": "^3.3.1"
```

the tricky and the last part is to include jquery.min.js on your .angular-cli.json file

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
  ],
```

hope this helps.